# Field with null are still indexed in ES 7.5

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

am seeing Field with Null are still indexing in ES 7.5 but according to ES "A null value cannot be indexed or searched. When a field is set to null". I remember when same field we passed with null on calling buklupdate API it was not indexed in ES 5.5 and only fields specified in mapping are indexed and ignored other fields(not part of mapping) with null even we included on the request.

would be great help  if get to know any specific flag to be turned on to resolve this in ES 7.5 ?.

FYI: we set dynamic as strict in mapping. thank you !

Comment: The null_value only influences how data is indexed, it doesn’t modify the _source document. So you will see it in _source but can't search on it. Can you add the query you are using for searching it and result

Comment: Sorry for the delay. yes you are right!, cant' searched it. my question was like when I send a field with null even its not part of mapping the field automatically ignored not part of _source in ES 5.5 but after migrated 7.7 am seeing the fame field is included as part of _source with null.. provided I set this as dynamic:false at the mapping level (index level not required as no type in 7.7) and not even specified ignore attribute for the field. so what I am looking for is even 7.7should behave same like 5.5 if I send a field with null it should ignore and not included as part _source in 7.7?